# Генератор qr код в боте телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram, бот, qrcode

У меня есть бот по генерация qr кодов ,но дело в том что он делает обычный qr код
[image: Вот он]

Но мне нужно делать вот такие

[image: Вот]

Кто может помочь вот код который уже имеется

```
def make_image_qrcode(data: Union[int, str]) -> str:
"""
Формирует QRCode из входных данных и сохраняет в временных файлах.
:return: Путь до qrcode
"""
code = str(data)
format = '.png'
image_title = f'{data}{format}'
dir = f'data{os.sep}tmp{os.sep}{image_title}'
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
    box_size=20,
    border=2
)
qr.add_data(data)
image = qr.make_image()
image.save(f'{dir}')

return dir
```

Comment: Посмотрите в строну python-barcode https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы он именно в кодировке EAN-13 был, как можно было бы поменять в моём коде её

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите 12 цифр')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    # проверка на количество и цифры
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(
        barcode.get('ean13', str(message.text), writer=ImageWriter()).save(f'files/{str(message.text)}'), 'rb'))
```

Comment: У меня бот на aiogram, а это вроде telebot

Comment: суть одна и та же. поменяйте методы под свои

Answer (score 3):

Баркод создаем с помощью библиотеки [`python-barcode`](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode). Чтобы она сохраняла не только `svg`, нужна обязательно установка [`Pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Нужно учитывать при составлении пути, что расширение добавляется автоматом и его не нужно лишний раз указывать. Путь сохранения выдается на методе `save()`.

```
import os
from typing import Union

import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter


def make_image_barcode(data: Union[int, str]) -> str:
    try:
        code = str(data)
        ean = barcode.get('ean13', code, writer=ImageWriter())
        filepath = ean.save(f'data{os.sep}tmp{os.sep}{code}')
        return f'{filepath}'
    except (barcode.errors.IllegalCharacterError, barcode.errors.NumberOfDigitsError) as e:
        return print(e)  # Выводит в консоль ошибку, если ввод не по EAN13
        # return None  # Можно использовать возврат None, чтобы бот понимал, что картинки нет.


inp = input('введите 12 цифр')
filepath = make_image_barcode(inp)
```

Comment: ошибка EAN code can only contain numbers.

Comment: хотя вроде пишу цифрами

Comment: Там должно быть 12 цифр

Comment: а можно сделать чтобы человек сам вписывал цифры которые ему надо
а не которые я задал?

Comment: Внизу в последних строках пример использования. Подавайте на вход, что ввел пользователь. Немного обновил функцию

Comment: Cпасибо это работает ,но это в консоле а как перевести на бота в телеграмм ,как было с обычным qr

Comment: Функция работает аналогично Вашей. На входе код, на выходе картинка с путем до нее. Дальше в своем коде уже ее размещаете. Единственный момент, что в случае ошибки у меня возвращается текст ошибки. Для обработки ботом там можно `return None` вернуть, к примеру.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как именно этот ввод перенести в бота, А не оставить в консоле

Comment: Также, как и с функцией по созданию QR-кода.

Comment: Ладно буду разбираться, а так спасибо)